# undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.4'

Tags: linux, ldd

First off,  please keep in mind that I'm new to linux.
I'm having problems compiling my project. I keep get the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Robot.dir/source/ModuleHandler.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.4'
>   //lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

First off the correct directory is: `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so`
Rather than: `//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so`

I've tried updating my ldconfig.conf file, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, using `ldd -r`
to no avail.

CMAKE is used to create the make file.

I've previously had no problems compiling. It started either when I did a apt-get upgrade or after a tried cross-compiling from VS.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

//Nathan

Comment: Is expected that you're trying to link your program against an ARM-specific library?

Comment: No idea. Assuming it is however...?

Comment: Well, likely it's a mistake. Normally if you have a x86 compatible workstation, you should use an "ordinary" compiler which doesn't try to use libraries for cross-compiling. What hardware and linux distributions do you use?

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the problem by adding: 
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ldl -lpthread")

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the problem by adding: 
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ldl -lpthread")
to the CMakeLists.txt file.
But if you're interested. I've been "normally" compiling my project remotely on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Wheezy). However I've been coding in Visual Studio, copying source files to The Pi and then compiling. Not very effecient. Therefore I tried using VisualGDB to build and that's most likely when the problem ensued.
Nevertheless thanks again!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, the man page for the symbol you can't find tells you what libraries you need to link in.  In your case:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

Note the line:

> Link with *-ldl*.

Comment: In short: `./configure LIBS='-ldl'`.

Answer (score 0):

For me reinstalling libglfw3-dev worked (`sudo apt install libglfw3-dev`). I suspect this had been removed during an update.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to clang. That fixed my problem

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
cmake ..
```